# Array of integers into array of ranges

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I'm trying to figure out how I can change array of integers into array of ranges.
For example I want to take this array:

```
ar = [0, 49, 14, 30, 40, 23, 59, 101]
```

into

```
ar = [0..49, 14..30, 40..23, 59..101]
```

Given array always will be even. I want to take each two values as borders of ranges.

I have tried to seperate it for two arrays. One with odd indexes second with even.

```
a = ar.select.with_index{|_,i| (i+1) % 2 == 1}
b = ar.select.with_index{|_,i| (i+1) % 2 == 0}
```

I don't have an idea how to use them to create ranges, also I would like to avoid creating redundant variables like `a` and `b`. 
I don't want to sort any values. Range `40..23` is intentional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 ar.each_slice(2).map { | a, b | a..b }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really concise.

Answer (score 2):

I would do as @undur_gongor's suggests, but here's another way:

```
e = ar.to_enum
b = []
loop do
  b << (e.next..e.next)
end
b 
  #=> [0..49, 14..30, 40..23, 59..101]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_ar = []

ar.each_slice(2) do |r|
    new_ar << Range.new(r[0], r[1])
end
```