# How to compress arrays of integers into an array of ranges and integers in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

I have a sorted array of integers, and  want all subsets of consecutive integers to be replaced with a range, so that:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,42]
```

is replaced with:

```
[1..10,42]
```

It's a list of rows from a Google spreadsheet that the user did not enter properly, and that could not be imported into another system's database.  There are a *lot* of rows, and often dozens in sequence.  It's much easier for a user to see that rows 3201-3379 are all bad, rather than having to read every single row number individually.

I'm not asking for "[Array of integers into array of ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031972/array-of-integers-into-array-of-ranges)".

I know how to write the code, and I'm happy to do so, but not if someone has already done it.  My current code is not elegant and I'm not going to bother refactoring it if there's something well tested and optimized already out there.

Comment: Asking for a (3rd-party) API / library has a specific close reason. Yes, this task is useful and has been written (in dozens of languages). No, it’s not in the standard library provided by Ruby. Ruby also doesn’t provide a standard library function to generate a Fibonacci sequence.. although such is easy to write.

Comment: _"My current code is not elegant"_ – doesn't matter. Please show it anyway so we can see the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect this question has been asked at SO, but the answer in not in my Rolodesk. It's easy enough to do, however.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20]

arr.slice_when { |x,y| y > x+1 }.
    map { |a| a.size == 1 ? a.first : a.first..a.last }
  #=> [1..3, 5..8, 10, 12..14, 17..18, 20]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

We first compute the enumerator

```
enum = arr.slice_when { |x,y| y > x+1 }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x...0000...fe0>:each>
```

We can convert `enum` to an array to see the elements that will be generated by the enumerator and fed to `map`:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18], [20]]
```

As an exercise, see if there is another [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html) method you could use instead of `slice_when`. (Hint: consider the [Great Peanut Butter Debate](https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/smooth-vs-chunky-peanut-butter_n_5609435).)

Comment: Exactly where I was going to point the OP. Enumerable, and its documentation, contains a wealth of information. It's "elegant". And, yeah, somewhere out there I have an answer doing this, but beats me where.

Comment: Ha! Sometimes it's easier to start typing than to search.